# Changing structure of WooCommerce shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have installed WooCommerce on my page, and I'm displaying features posts using shortcode inside of a php file.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[featured_products per_page="3" columns="3"]'); ?>
```

It displays features products, but the problem is that its displaying them in UL and LI elements. Is there a way I can change how its displayed(for example displaying them inside of a bootstrap row and columns), so it can match the structure of my front end.

Comment: there is a template for featured posts in the woocommerce plugin folder - in the top of that template, there is instruction on how to overwrite it in your child theme.

Comment: I cant find it. Is that the way to change structure of data which is being displayed using shortcodes?

Comment: with featured products, you can also build your own wp_query, but the template should be called 'content-widget-product.php' inside the templates folder.

Comment: @Stender do you maybe know some tutorial for changing structure of shortcode? I cant figure it out still.

Comment: You can pass the class attribute into the shortcode which will add classes to the div surrounding the ul element.  [featured_products per_page="3" columns="3" class="my-class"]  Without editing the template files though you will still have the ul and li elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it. Please follow the below instructions

1. Create a folder named "woocommerce" in your theme folder.
2. Copy template files in directory `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates` from woocommerce plugin folder and paste these files in the woocommerce folder of your theme.
3. Now you can modify WooCommerce templates from your theme.
4. Open loop folder and edit `loop-start.php` and `loop-end.php` remove `<ul>` and place your bootstrap divs here.
5. Open `content-product.php` to change the `<li>` to your bootstrap columns.

Comment: Doesn't `loop-start.php` and `loop-end.php` affect other things too, not only the `[featured_products]` output? It's not clear from the question if OP is looking for a way to only change the shortcode, or if this is meant for other things too?

Comment: it will chnage every where you are showing procusts  weather it is featured or latest or shop page, or category page where loop is used to show the products

Comment: so if the loop start/end templates are modified then we would need to adjust some other template files as well, than just the `content-product.php` file, right?

Comment: if you are facing any problem other then this add me on your skype rajkumar.gaur.91@gmail.com